# Solving Recursive Product of Array without .slice()

Tags: javascript, algorithm, function, recursion, data-structures

I was given the advice to not to rely on built in javascript functions when solving Data Structures and Algorithm questions for interview prep and I am having a problem with my code. Here is the original question with my original solution.

Write a recursive function called productOfArray which takes in an array of numbers and returns the product of them all.  Examples

```js
function productOfArray(arr) {
  if (arr.length === 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  return arr[0] * productOfArray(arr.slice(1));
}

console.log(productOfArray([1, 2, 3])) // 6
console.log(productOfArray([1, 2, 3, 10])) // 60
```

I have tried making my own function to replace the .slice below but to no avail  … Thank You all for your time and help. PS .. What are your thoughts on built in methods while studying for an interview?

```js
function productOfArray(arr) {
  function arrSliced(arr, begin, end) {

    let slicedArray = [];

    if (end === null || end > arr.length) {
      end === arr.length;
    }

    for (let i = begin; i < end; i++) {
      slicedArray.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }

  if (arr.length === 0) {
    return 1;
  }

  return arr[0] * arrSliced(productOfArray, 1);
}

let test = productOfArray([1, 2, 3]);
console.log(test);
```

**Update trying Destructuring**

```js
function productOfArray(arr) {
  if (arr.length === 0) {
    return 1;
  }

  const [head, ...tail] = arr;

  return head * productOfArray(tail);
}

let test = productOfArray(3, 2, 5);
console.log(test);
```

Comment: Weird advice to be honest

Comment: Interesting maybe i'll take it with a grain of salt.. or they just want me to understand whats going on under the hood a little bit idk.. thanks for your input

Comment: "*not to rely on built in javascript functions*" - that's pointless. You need the builtins to write basic javascript. Whether it's `.push()`, `.length` or `.slice()`, or `[Symbol.iterator]()` in destructuring. What the advice probably was meant to say: if you are supposed to write a sort algorithm, don't use the builtin `sort` method.

Answer (score 1):

[Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) can do the job:

```js
function productOfArray(arr) {
  if (arr.length === 0) {
    return 1;
  }

  const [head, ...tail] = arr;

  return head * productOfArray(tail);
}
```

Now, `head` is the first element, and `tail` is the rest.

Comment: hmmm thanks for your help!  I tried this and got TypeError: arr is not iterable

Comment: Sounds like you didn't give it an array?

Comment: (⚆ᗝ⚆) ... Maybe ... i just edited my original post to show an update of what i tried.. reading up on Destructuring right now

Comment: You miss `[]` in your attempt

Answer (score 0):

Fixed your code

```js
function productOfArray(arr) {
  function arrSliced(arr, begin, end) {
    const slicedArray = [];

    // if end is not provided it will be undefined not null
    if (end === undefined || end > arr.length) {
      // = is assignment, === is comparison
      end = arr.length;
    }

    for (let i = begin; i < end; i++) {
      slicedArray.push(arr[i]);
    }

    // you have to return the new array
    return slicedArray
  }

  if (arr.length === 0) {
    return 1;
  }

  // you tried to pass the function here instead of array
  return arr[0] * productOfArray(arrSliced(arr, 1));
}

let test = productOfArray([1, 2, 3]);
console.log(test);
```

Comment: (o^-')b You're a wizard ! Thanks for your comments too ! Do you think  Destructuring like the answer posted above is better practice ??

Comment: As good as the slice version. To be clear. In professional code bases writing your own slice wouldn't be acceptable - it's less readable and can introduce errors. But writing code like that can help your understand the language more.